# How to fetch parent-child hierarchy

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to fetch parent-child hierarchy when we pass 'NAME' as '9780748700585' in TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC table?Relation between TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC and TEMP_NODE tables are CHILD_ID is foreign key and ID is  primary key in TEMP_NODE.

final out put should be

```
('1202','1223','9781424005468_p01_covpdf.zip');
('1202','1226','9781424005468_p01_hipdf.zip');
('1202','1229','9781424005468_p01_pod.zip');
('1202','1232','9781424005468_p01_pod_chaitu.zip');


 CREATE TABLE "TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC" ("PARENT_ID" VARCHAR2(20), "CHILD_ID" VARCHAR2(20), "NAME" VARCHAR2(2000))
REM INSERTING into TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC (PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,NAME) values ('1141','1143','9780748700585');
Insert into TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC (PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,NAME) values ('1143','1202','testfolder1');
Insert into TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC (PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,NAME) values ('1202','1223','9781424005468_p01_covpdf.zip');
Insert into TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC (PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,NAME) values ('1202','1226','9781424005468_p01_hipdf.zip');
Insert into TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC (PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,NAME) values ('1202','1229','9781424005468_p01_pod.zip');
Insert into TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC (PARENT_ID,CHILD_ID,NAME) values ('1202','1232','9781424005468_p01_pod_chaitu.zip');


 CREATE TABLE "TEMP_NODE" ("ID" VARCHAR2(20), "NAME" VARCHAR2(20))
REM INSERTING into TEMP_NODE
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into TEMP_NODE (ID,NAME) values ('1143','product');
Insert into TEMP_NODE (ID,NAME) values ('1202','folder');
Insert into TEMP_NODE (ID,NAME) values ('1223','asset');
Insert into TEMP_NODE (ID,NAME) values ('1226','asset');
Insert into TEMP_NODE (ID,NAME) values ('1229','asset');
Insert into TEMP_NODE (ID,NAME) values ('1232','asset');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query produces result you wanted:

```
SQL> select c.parent_id, c.child_id, c.name
  2  from temp_child_assoc c
  3  where level = 3
  4  connect by prior c.child_id = c.parent_id
  5  start with c.name = '9780748700585'
  6  order siblings by c.child_id;

PARENT_ID  CHILD_ID   NAME
---------- ---------- -----------------------------------
1202       1223       9781424005468_p01_covpdf.zip
1202       1226       9781424005468_p01_hipdf.zip
1202       1229       9781424005468_p01_pod.zip
1202       1232       9781424005468_p01_pod_chaitu.zip

SQL>
```

However, I don't understand what's the purpose of the TEMP_NODE table (as we don't use it), and why you don't want CHILD_ID's 1143 (level 1) and 1202 (level 2).

**[EDIT, after reading the comment]**

Aha, you don't want *folders*. Why didn't you say so?

If we join those tables (so that we could restrict returned data on *folders*) and remove the LEVEL condition, this is what you get:

```
SQL> select level, c.parent_id, c.child_id, c.name
  2  from temp_child_assoc c join temp_node n on c.child_id = n.id
  3  where n.name <> 'folder'
  4  connect by prior c.child_id = c.parent_id
  5  start with c.name = '9780748700585'
  6  order siblings by c.child_id;

     LEVEL PARENT_ID  CHILD_ID   NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------------------------
         1 1141       1143       9780748700585
         3 1202       1223       9781424005468_p01_covpdf.zip
         3 1202       1226       9781424005468_p01_hipdf.zip
         3 1202       1229       9781424005468_p01_pod.zip
         3 1202       1232       9781424005468_p01_pod_chaitu.zip

SQL>
```

The first row is the one you don't need. Why? This is not a *folder* but *product*, so ... I'm afraid I still don't understand the requirement.

Comment: temp_node will tell you that its an asset.we want only assets inside the product.we dont want folders inside folders.you will know whether its an 'asset' or 'folder' if you go to temp_node table.  we cannot put level in the query so multiple levels can be there.